# Data extraction from excel with operators is unable to store values

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a Excel file with two columns. One has a name other has the corresponding mass to it. I have used the corresponding lines to read it and find the position of the name. But when I am trying to find the mass to the corresponding name as shown below it is not able to store it in the memory. In the Excel file, I have the mass values as  1.989*10^30. This seems to affect the code as the same code works fine when the cells in the excel has just numeric values.

```
majbod = 'Sun';
minbod = 'Earth';
majbodin = readtable("Major_and_Minor_Bodies.xlsx","Sheet",1);
minbodin = readtable("Major_and_Minor_Bodies.xlsx","Sheet",2);
MAJORBODY = table2array(majbodin(:,"Major_Body"));
MINORBODY = table2array(minbodin(:,"Minor_Body"));
mmaj = table2array(majbodin(:,"Mass"));
mmin = table2array(minbodin(:,"Mass"));
selected_majbody = find(strcmp(MAJORBODY,majbod));
selected_minbody = find(strcmp(MINORBODY,minbod));
M = mmaj(selected_majbody);
m = mmin(selected_minbody);
disp([M ;m])
```

Is there a better way to write the code compared to the way which I wrote?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does it's best to figure out what kind of data is in each cell. Since your data has something besides just numbers, Excel treats it like a string. You have a couple of options for getting around that:

1. If you put an equals sign in front of it, it will treat it like an equation, and calculate the value of 1.989*10^3 for you. this will be a number.
2. Since scientific notation is so common, programmers have created a shortcut for representing it. They often use the character 'E' where you use "*10^". This means that if you type "1.989E30", excel will recognize that as a number.
3. If keeping the current string format is very important, you could probably modify the string during extraction - replace '*10^' with E, and then whatever language you are using will have a string to number parser you can use.
4. If the real problem is that the real numbers are just too long in Excel, you can always format the cell that they are in. (right click the cell, select format cells, then select scientific.)

Good luck